# How to find a similar word for a misspelled one in PHP?

Tags: php, string, string-comparison, similarity

I'll explain my problem:

I have a database table called `country`. It has two columns: `ID` and `name`.

When I want to search for `'paris'`, but misspelled the word: `'pares'` (`'e'` instead of `'i'`), I won't get any result from DB.

I want the the system to suggest similar words that could help in the search.

So, I am looking for help writing a script that makes suggestions from the DB that contain similar words like: paris, paredes, ... etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In PHP you should use [`metaphone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php) it is more accurate than [`soundex`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php).

But your problem is getting the data from the database. You've not mentioned the DB. In MySQL you can make use of the [`SOUNDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) function. You just need to change your where clause in the query from

```
...where city = '$input_city'
```

to

```
... where soundex(city) = soundex('$input_city')
```

or even better you can use [`SOUNDS LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like) operator as

```
... where city sounds like '$input_city'
```

Comment: **Note** : `soundex` is good for English words and integers, but other languages problem.

Comment: @codaddict Is there are any way to order by relevance?

Answer (score 10):

[soundex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) will return a numerical code for a word that represents its sound.  Words that sound similar will have the same soundex code.  You could have a table with words and their soundex codes that you could use to look up similar sounding words.  You could then sort them using their [levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) distance.

If you're looking for something simpler and you just want to handle typos in your DB queries, you can do

`select * from country where city SOUNDS LIKE 'Paris'` instead of `select * from country where city='Paris'`

Answer (score 5):

Basically you need to check similarity against a valid array of names when you got no results from your db.

My idea:

- User searching some name
- No exact results
- Fetch all names from db
- Using [levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) calculate the most exact tip for user to return

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQL, you'll want to use a `MATCH() AGAINST()` statement, where `MATCH()` is given a comma-delimited list of `FULLTEXT` columns and `AGAINST()` is given your string to match against.  The statement returns the relevance of your match (between 0 and 1) which you can use to determine whether or not to return rows.

More info on the [MySQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Edit: the sound suggestions are good ideas, however certain misspellings will completely change the pronunciation of a word and thus you may not be able to provide good suggestions if you use that method.

Answer (score 2):

Since most of the PHP internal methods are already covered, you can also take a look at the Yahoo Boss Spelling Suggestion Service, its quite usefull -> http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/boss_guide/Spelling_Suggest.html